# Soundcloud API as back-end music radio service

Tags: soundcloud, backend

Can I use your API as media library for broadcasting to and users between custom mobile client? I mean legal side by agreement. 
Also can I change broadcast stream quality at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per their API terms of use, under their "Content and Privacy" section, found at the following link: https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/terms-of-use#privacy

"Regardless of any permissions set by any Uploader with respect to any User Content, you must not use the SoundCloud® API, or any User Content accessible via the SoundCloud® API, for any of the following purposes:"
...

"to create any webcasting radio app"